# Direct phone call without pop-up in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift5

```
if let url = URL(string: "tel:/ +91******* ) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

However, when touched startCall Button, a pop up appears asking to "Call" or "Cancel". Is there a way to take the user directly call and avoid this pop up in iOS (Swift 5)?

Comment: I sure hope not.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to take the user directly call and avoid this pop up in iOS (swift 5)?

No there is not, and that is by design.

Apple believes (and I agree) that only the user should be able to initiate phone calls on their phone. If apps could trigger phone calls without the user's permission it would allow all sorts of mischief.

This is a deliberate security feature of the OS.

Comment: By using Intents can we call directly by pressing Button ? is it possible ?

Comment: No, I don’t believe it is possible to trigger a phone call unless you display the Apple dialog to the user.

Comment: In Voice Over IP it is possible right ? Audio Call through internet.

Comment: Voice over IP is an app-provided feature, and not subject to the same tight control that cell phone-calls are put under. So yes, I assume that an app could initiate a VoIP phone-call without the user having to trigger it with a system dialog. (Disclaimer: I haven't tried to implement VoIP on iOS, nor have I looked closely at iOS support for it, so my answer is based on an incomplete understanding.)